# New instance of ViewModel doesn't update SelectedItem binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I tried asking a question earlier and it was my first post on StackOverflow so it got a bit messy.  I'll try to make this one a bit more clear.

So I have an InventoryView that contains a ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection and the SelectedIngredient is bound to an Ingredient object.

The program correctly reads from the database and populates all fields based on the SelectedIngredient. However, when I call my Save method, it seems to create a new instance of the View model.  This wouldn't be a problem normally as all the properties are correct except for SelectedIngredient which seems to be initialized with null and never calls to get the current value before working with it.

I was wondering if anyone had any solutions to my problem.  I am fairly new to MVVM and Databinding and this problem has had me pretty stumped for a while.  I'm assuming I either need the Save method to use the same instance of the ViewModel or have the new instance get the value of SelectedIngredient when it's created.  Neither of which I know how to attempt to solve.

If more information is needed, there are links to the full .cs and .xaml files as well as the entire project on GitHub (which I can't link as I cannot have more than 2 links yet haha.)

Thank you all!

[InventoryView.xaml](https://github.com/ljrobison/MineralDatabaseApp/blob/master/Views/InventoryView.xaml) (Link to full file)

```
<Window x:Class="MineralDatabase.App.Views.InventoryView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfToolkit="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MineralDatabase.App.Helpers"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Inventory" Height="400" Width="440">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IngredientTypeConverter x:Key="IngredientTypeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0">
        <ToolBar>
            <Button x:Name="btnNew" ToolTip="Add a new ingredient."  Click="btnNew_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/new.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="New"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnRename" ToolTip="Rename current ingredient." Click="btnRename_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/rename.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="Rename"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" ToolTip="Deletes current Ingredient." >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/delete.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="Delete"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button x:Name="btnManufacturers" ToolTip="Displays manufacturer info." Click="btnManufacturers_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/manufacturers.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="Manufacturers"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button x:Name="SaveAllChanges" ToolTip="Save all changes." Click="btnSave_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/save.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="Save"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnExit" ToolTip="Exit ingredients manager." Click="btnExit_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/icons/toolbar/exit.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0"><Run Text="Exit"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Ingredient Name" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxIngredientName" Margin="0,0,0,3" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientList}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIngredient, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Manufacturer"/>
                    <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,3"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierNameList}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Manufacturer}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Type" Margin="0,0,0,3"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="Base" Margin="0,0,0,3" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Type, Converter={StaticResource IngredientTypeConverter},ConverterParameter=0}"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="Oxide" Margin="0,0,0,3" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Type, Converter={StaticResource IngredientTypeConverter},ConverterParameter=1}"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="Additive" Margin="0,0,0,3" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Type, Converter={StaticResource IngredientTypeConverter},ConverterParameter=2}"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="Other" Margin="0,0,0,3" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Type, Converter={StaticResource IngredientTypeConverter},ConverterParameter=3}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Cost">
                        <Border Margin="5">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Cost" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                    <wpfToolkit:DecimalUpDown Width="75" Value="0.00" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Volume" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                    <wpfToolkit:DecimalUpDown Width="75" Value="0.00" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Button Content="Add to Inventory" Width="100"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Inventory amount" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        <wpfToolkit:DecimalUpDown Width="80"  Value="{Binding SelectedIngredient.InventoryAmount}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Inventory alarm" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                        <wpfToolkit:DecimalUpDown Width="80"  Value="{Binding SelectedIngredient.InventoryThreshold}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Storage location" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,12,0" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Location}" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="2">
                <TextBlock Text="Notes" Margin="0,3,5,0" />
                <wpfToolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding SelectedIngredient.Notes}" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                    <wpfToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                        <wpfToolkit:RtfFormatter />
                    </wpfToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                </wpfToolkit:RichTextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[InventoryViewModel.cs](https://github.com/ljrobison/MineralDatabaseApp/blob/master/ViewModels/InventoryViewModel.cs) (Link to full file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using MineralDatabase.App.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MineralDatabase.App.ViewModels
{
    public partial class InventoryViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        #region Constructor
        public InventoryViewModel()
        {
            GetAllIngredients();
            GetAllSuppliers();
            GetSuppliersNames();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        MineralDBEntities db = new MineralDBEntities();

        private ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> _supplierList;
        public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> SupplierList
        {
            get { return _supplierList; }
            set
            {
                _supplierList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SupplierList);
            }
        }

        private Manufacturer _selectedSupplier;
        public Manufacturer SelectedSupplier
        {
            get { return _selectedSupplier; }
            set
            {
                _selectedSupplier = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedSupplier);
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Ingredient> _ingredientList;
        public ObservableCollection<Ingredient> IngredientList
        {
            get { return _ingredientList; }
            set
            {
                _ingredientList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IngredientList);
            }
        }

        private Ingredient _selectedIngredient;
        public Ingredient SelectedIngredient
        { 
            get
            {
                return _selectedIngredient;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedIngredient != value)
                {
                    _selectedIngredient = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedIngredient);
                }
            }
        }

        private List<string> _supplierNameList;
        public List<string> SupplierNameList
        {
            get { return _supplierNameList; }
            set
            {
                _supplierNameList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SupplierNameList);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void GetAllIngredients()
        {
            db.Ingredients.Load();
            IngredientList = db.Ingredients.Local;
        }

        public void GetAllSuppliers()
        {
            db.Manufacturers.Load();
            SupplierList = db.Manufacturers.Local;
        }

        public void GetSuppliersNames()
        {
            db.Manufacturers.Load();
            var result = db.Manufacturers.Select(x => x.CompanyName).ToList();
            SupplierNameList = result;
        }

        public void SaveAllChanges()
        {
            var result = db.Ingredients.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name == SelectedIngredient.Name);
            if (result != null)
            {
                result = SelectedIngredient;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                Ingredient i = new Ingredient();
                i = SelectedIngredient;

                if (i.Name != null || i.Name != String.Empty)
                {
                    db.Ingredients.Add(i);
                    try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                    {
                        Exception raise = dbEx;
                        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {
                            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                                    validationError.ErrorMessage);
                                // raise a new exception nesting
                                // the current instance as InnerException
                                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                            }
                        }
                        throw raise;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the code gets to your Constructor again? and also put a break point on the set method of your SelcetedIngredient just to see when the value does become  null. Those are the few basic checks you can do to see what is wrong in the application.

Comment: I have done that. When selecting an item in the ComboBox, SelectedIngredient seems to get and set correctly. However, tt becomes null as soon as the SaveAllChanges method is called and never gets/sets the SelectedIngredient resulting in it containing null. But everything else like IngredientList is correct. Before I click the save button everything is correct, but when doing so it creates a new ViewModel where everything is correct except the SelectedIngredient which is never enters the get of.